# How do I return a string from a Rust function in Nodejs-WebAssembly using wasm bindgen?

Tags: node.js, rust, webassembly

I'm new to Rust and WASM and struggling to get a first program running.

```
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = { version = "0.2.63" }
```

I have the following Rust that compiles to WASM

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

// When the `wee_alloc` feature is enabled, use `wee_alloc` as the global
// allocator.
#[cfg(feature = "wee_alloc")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
    // let val = ["Hello", name].join(" ");
    let val = format!("Hello {}", name);
    return val;
}
```

And my node code (inspired by https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-with-webassembly),

```
const fs = require("fs");
const wasmBuffer = fs.readFileSync("../pkg/hello_world_bg.wasm");
WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuffer)
  .then((wasmModule) => {
    // Exported function live under instance.exports
    const greet = wasmModule.instance.exports.greet;
    console.log(typeof greet);
    const greeting = greet("Simon");
    console.log("x", greeting);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

This logs

```
function
x undefined
```

I tried two ways of concatenating the strings, or perhaps I am doing something wrong with the return value?

Comment: @DenysSéguret `wasm_bindgen` would generally take care of the necessary glue to return a `String` from a function in Rust. https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/string.html

Comment: Something else might be at play here, but a [mre] is lacking: please specify relevant dependency versions and remove unrelated code (`mod utils;`) while ensuring that it is complete and enables other people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but the function body of `greet` only needs to be `format!("Hello {}", name)`.

Comment: `mod utils` was put there by `cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template` - I have removed that import s it does not seem to be essential

Comment: Thanks @DenysSéguret - starting with `wasm-pack build --target nodejs` I was able to use the js file produced to call greet. That was simple for me, even though the js file I'm importing is impossible to follow at present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using WebInstantiate in node without more boilerplate, just like you did, I got the same result (`undefined`). What works seamlessly in the browser doesn't work so well in node.

But I got string exchange working when specifically building a node module with

```
wasm-pack build --target nodejs
```

With a node module, usage is also much simpler:

```js
const wasmModule = require("./pkg/hello_world.js");
const greet = wasmModule.greet;
const greeting = greet("Simon");
console.log('greeting:', greeting);
```